# How can I read all my files in Visual Studio 2022, and juste keep a label?

Tags: javascript, c#

I create a table dictionary in SQL Server, and I would like, to create a script who read all my files in my project (with Visual Studio 2022), and when it find a new word than it save it in my Table.
Do you have some advice ? I don't really know how to do it. Can I do something with Regex class?

My files are in C#, JavaScript and HTML

```
public class Test
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        // Define a regular expression for repeated words.
        Regex rx = new Regex(@"\b(?<word>\w+)\s+(\k<word>)\b",
          RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

        // Define a test string.
        string text = "The the quick brown fox  fox jumps over the lazy dog dog.";

        // Find matches.
        MatchCollection matches = rx.Matches(text);

        // Report the number of matches found.
        Console.WriteLine("{0} matches found in:\n   {1}",
                          matches.Count,
                          text);

        // Report on each match.
        foreach (Match match in matches)
        {
            GroupCollection groups = match.Groups;
            Console.WriteLine("'{0}' repeated at positions {1} and {2}",
                              groups["word"].Value,
                              groups[0].Index,
                              groups[1].Index);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what I found on microsoft.com. Is it possible to adapt this, to do what I need ?

Comment: create a [visual studio extension](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=851731) to solve this

Comment: doing this, you can just loop through each file in the projects root directory and then just use regex to search for words and then do your database stuff, if you want you could add a config to your project, that the extension can load, which will allow you to have a reusable extension for other projects, but each project can load its own configs such as database login details, etc.

Comment: What does that even mean? What is the schema? How would Regex help? What is the purpose of all this? What do you consider "a word"?

Comment: And what's the point for using regex? You don't need to find a word in a text, but to find a word in the dictionary, right? For each file, iterate word by word. If the word is not in the dictionary, then add it.